# Create array with function and size

Tags: matlab

Recently I wrote this statement

```
v = arrayfun(@(x) sum(randn(1, 4).^2), zeros(1, 1000000));
```

to create a new vector and now I'm asking if there exists a function in Matlab to avoid the creation of the unnecessary second vector `zeros(1, 1000000)`. I'm looking for something like

```
v = FUN(@someInitFunction, [rows, cols]);
```

without loops, recursion and unnecessary allocation where `someInitFunction` is given and can't be changed. Does Matlab provide such a function `FUN`? A simple *"No, it doesn't exist"* would be a valid answer for me.

To summarize the function `FUN`: I want to create a new array by calling a function `someInitFunction` for each element of this new array. The array should be equivalent to

```
[
    someInitFunction() someInitFunction() ...;
    someInitFunction() someInitFunction() ...;
    .
    .
    .
    someInitFunction() someInitFunction() ...
]
```

Comment: Is the init function dependant on its indices/position in the output array ?

Comment: @Hoki No, it's always the same call. Like in the first example it doesn't even have parameters.

Comment: How generic should this be? It looks like your statement would be much simpler if it were just `v = sum( randn( 1000000, 4 ).^2, 2 );` A simple loop would also skirt the need to create the huge array...

Comment: I suddenly have the feeling that you want the `initFunction` to be evaluated not only once but _for each element_ of the array, in which case my current answer is useless. Please confirm.

Comment: @Hoki Yes, the `initFunction` is evaluated once for each element.

Comment: @Wolfie As I said the function is given and can't be changed.

Comment: No, it doesn't exist. You can write your own version! Instead of `zeros(1, 1000000)` you can use `1: 1000000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no builtin function for that. It's relatively easy to create your own however.

You asked a solution *without loop* but the current solution you are using (`arrayfun`) uses loop under the hood, and generally coding the same in a properly organised loop is actually faster than `arrayfun`.

For your case, the function `GenArrayFun.m` :

```
function out = GenArrayFun(initFunction , arraySize)

    out = zeros(arraySize) ;
    for k=1:numel(out)
        out(k) = initFunction() ;
    end
```

It has a loop, but no more than `arrayfun`, and seem to perform twice as fast (at least on my installation, R2016a, win10):

```
initFunction = @() sum(randn(1, 4).^2) ;

tic
v = arrayfun(@(x) sum(randn(1, 4).^2), zeros(1, 1000000));
toc
tic
out = GenArrayFun( initFunction , [1,1000000] );
toc
```

Sorry I did not take the time to build a proper `timeit` benchmark for such a small example, I think the results are significant enough to notice a difference:

```
Elapsed time is 6.815043 seconds. % arrayfun
Elapsed time is 3.060161 seconds. % GenArrayFun
```

And just to make sure it evaluate the `initFunction` for every element:

```
>> out = GenArrayFun( initFunction , [2,3] )
out =
          6.25676106665387          6.52758807745462          2.99236122767462
         0.386750258201569         0.566092999842791          2.21158011908878
```

Comment: As you can see each value of the array is same. `v = arrayfun(@() sum(randn(1, 4).^2), zeros(1, 1000000));` creates an array with different values.

Comment: Yes I got that feeling after I posted the answer. I was blind to that because on my Matlab 2016a your statement does not run (it probably need a version of Matlab which support implicit expansion).

Comment: That's my mistake. I only tried it in Octave instead of Matlab. In Matlab the anonymous function need a parameter. I changed it in my question.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I rewrote a solution. Sorry it still has a loop but it's shorter to call and seems to be faster than `arrayfun`.